# Printing arraylist size crash

Tags: c, arrays, list, arraylist

I have a C program that implement arraylist (dynamic array,however I dont understand how or why i cannot print the array size.When I try to do so, the program just crash.Heres the program.

arraylist.c

```
#include "arraylist.h"

void arraylist_initial(struct arraylist *list) {
  list->size = 0;
  list->data = NULL;
}

int arraylist_get_size(const struct arraylist list) {
  return list.size;
}

value_type* arraylist_get_data_collection(const struct arraylist list) {
  return list.data;
}

void arraylist_set_data_collection(struct arraylist *list, value_type* data) {
  list->data = data;
}

void arraylist_add(struct arraylist *list, value_type value) {
  int size = arraylist_get_size(*list);
  value_type *new_data;

  new_data = realloc(list->data, (size + 1) * sizeof new_data[0]);

  if (new_data)
  {
      new_data[size] = value;
      arraylist_set_data_collection(list, new_data);
      ++list->size;
  }
}

value_type arraylist_get(const struct arraylist list, int index) {
  if(index < arraylist_get_size(list)) {
    return list.data[index];
  }
  else {
    return NULL;
  }
}

int arraylist_indexof(const struct arraylist list, value_type value) {
  int index = 0;
  for(; index != arraylist_get_size(list); ++index) {
    if(strcmp(list.data[index], value) == 0) {
      return index;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

int main(void){
  struct arraylist list;

  arraylist_initial(&list);

  arraylist_add(&list, "1");
  arraylist_add(&list, "2");
  arraylist_add(&list, "3");
  arraylist_add(&list, "4");
  arraylist_add(&list, "5");
  arraylist_add(&list, "6");
  arraylist_add(&list, "7");
  arraylist_get_size(list);


  int index = 0;
  for(; index != 8; ++index) {
    printf("CHECK: %s\n", arraylist_get(list, index));

  }

  return 0;
}
```

arraylist.h

```
#define _ARRAYLIST_H

#include <stdio.h>

typedef char* value_type;

struct arraylist {
  int size;
  value_type* data;
};

extern void arraylist_initial(struct arraylist *list);
extern int arraylist_get_size(const struct arraylist list);
extern value_type* arraylist_get_data_collection(const struct arraylist list);
extern void arraylist_set_data_collection(struct arraylist *list, value_type* data);
extern void arraylist_add(struct arraylist *list, value_type value);
extern value_type arraylist_get(const struct arraylist list, int index);
extern int arraylist_indexof(const struct arraylist list, value_type value);
```

In arraylist.c if I do

```
printf(arraylist_get_size_list(list));
```

It just crash and I dont get it?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I was remembering a time when you couldn't pass structs with C.  It looks like you can now.  They keep changing things.

Here's the real problem:  printf takes a string as the first argument.

Instead of:

```
printf(arraylist_get_size_list(list));
```

Try:

```
printf("size: %d\n", arraylist_get_size_list(list));
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.However,If i try what you said, I get  errors: incompatible type for argument 1 of "arraylist_get_size" and conflicting types for arraylist_get_size

Comment: See my update.  The passing of structs in ok.  I think your error was in what you passed to printf.

Comment: thank you.It works.however for the actual code, its says the size is 7.However,shouldnt it be 6? since it start at index 0 i think, it should be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 , why size is 7?